# How to get Process in windows mobile

Tags: c#, .net, c++, windows-mobile, winapi

i want to get the running process in .net compact framework  windows mobile..
i want to kill the running process.. but i know process.GetProcessesByName() function
is present in desktop, but for mobile its not supported i think so..
please let me know how to kill the presently running process in c# windows mobile.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey i found answer here it is

Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();

.net CF is crazy :-)